# Intercepting SMS Intents (non-default application)

Tags: android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat, telephony, smsmanager

I'm thinking about writing up an little app for Android that intercepts received texts and pushes them to a Windows computer, where you can respond to it. However, I know that you cannot send text messages on Android without being the default SMS app, and I don't want to make an entire texting client.. Just something that intercepts the text and displays it on Windows, but uses the default SMS app for sending and receiving. Is this possible?

Comment: "However, I know that you cannot send text messages on Android without being the default SMS app" -- any app with `SEND_SMS` can send an SMS message via `SmsManager`.

Comment: I thought that sending an SMS without the app being default would disallow it from being displayed in the default app?

Comment: Most versions of Android do not notify any SMS app of SMS messages sent by other apps via `SmsManager`. I seem to recall reading that `SmsManager` now writes to the standard outbox on Android 4.4, but I may be mis-remembering that.

Answer (score 0):

So to receive a SMS first you have to set an IntentFilter with highest priority. Like:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
filter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
registerReceiver(smsReceiver , filter);
```

Where smsReceiver is a class that extends BroadcastReceiver. Inside the onReceive method you can call abortBroadcast(); which will stop  the broadcasting of the "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" event. More info http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html.